# Do keyboards differ only by their respective scan codes?

Tags: c, operating-system, keyboard, driver, osdev

I am working on an operating system that I created as a hobby. Currently I am writing a PS/2 keyboard driver for my OS, and wondering whether other keyboards (eg, USB keyboards) differ from a PS/2 keyboard only by their respective scan codes.

Is this assumption true? Thanks in advance.

EDIT
Some details: My OS is 32-bit and so I am not using any hardware interrupts.

Comment: The "scan codes" of a USB keyboard are not so much indexes of a key table, rather the real characters of a US keyboard. Do some research on relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned PS/2 keyboards and other keyboards only differ in a few ways, the scan codes, the lights (eg caps lock, scroll lock) and extra features that the keyboard might have (card readers, etc).